# Why do some inbounds turtle.goto(x,y) calls create tkinter.Canvas items with negative coordinates?

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics

Where "inbounds" means -win_width/2 < x < win_width/2 and -win_height/2 y < win_height/2

My application produces a low resolution character map of the turtle graphics window.  My primary goal is to teach programming to the "new to programming".  I've found graphics display in turtle to be a useful tool.  But with the blind we have additional obstacles to overcome.  My application supports the blind programmer by converting the turtle graphic that their program creates into a map, consisting of characters.  This text can be sent to a Braille embosser, creating an embossed printout over which the programmer can traverse with fingers to see their production such as simple figures e.g. squares.  As a touch compromise we chose a character grid of 40 characters wide and 25 lines high.  We simulate color as  the first character of the color text(English).

To aid in my analysis and development, the application produces auxiliary output such as braille display windows.

My progress, so far includes two versions, both based on deriving a  class TurtleBraille based on Turtle which generates the expected turtle graphics plus the printed output(to be sent to the embosser), plus, if requested, Braille window display.

Versions:

1. Intercepting and then translating the turtle commands such as goto():

   a. passing command to turtle

   b. converting command into tkinter.Canvas commands such as canvas.create_line()

   Status: Working for the most part code: GitHub raysmith619/resource_lib (At beginning)
2. Letting the turtle commands, for the most part, pass on to turtle.

   a. We intercept some of the commands, such as goto for debugging and analysis.

   b. After all commands are complete - at (done(), mainloop()), we  "scrape" the tkinter Canvas.  We loop over the canvas area via subrectangle sections, using canvas.find_overlapping(subrectangle area) to determine which, if any, items intersect with the subrectangle to select the "BrailleCell" should be created for display.

Status: Working, with a Big problem code: GitHub raysmith619/TurtleBraille

Here is where our problem occurs:  The Canvas coordinates for the items often unexpectedly have negative coordinates giving translated x position and flipped y position.

Turtle Plot Overlayed with Braille Window

[image: Turtle Plot Overlayed with Braille Window]

To be honest, we had to fudge in order to get the figure displayed.   We describe a bit more in the GitHub readme.

For the interested, we include some shots of the working version 1.

Turtle Plot Snapshot

[image: Turtle plot]

Braille Window
[image]

Printed output - destined for Braille output device
[image]

Python program to create plots
[image]

Comment: The turtle and the underlying Tkinter Canvas simply have different coordinate systems - both in the location of the origin (center vs. upper left) and in the direction of the positive Y axis (up vs. down).  You're going to have to do some math to adjust for this.

Comment: Thanks,  It is as I've grown to suspect.  It just seams that, as turtle is based on tkinter and they are so closely related that if turtle, in standard mode, would either make the translation, say in the turtle.goto() call, or would explicitly document that no translation was made.  NOTE that if one restricts operation to say relative operations such as forward(), right()... turtle operations the connected Canvas coordinates come out fine.  I would have found a bit more documentation very helpful.

Comment: Turtle graphics *far* predates Tkinter.  It was originally developed in the late 1960s, in conjunction with the Logo programming language.  When the Python version was written the existing conventions for coordinates were kept, even though this required translation.

Comment: This is true, however, turtle, as part of Python/tkinter exposes tkinter and in particular the Canvas module. This link would be improved if the connection was improved or at least documented a bit.  In my case it would better support tinker level extensions (e.g. canvas scraping).  Thanks again for the comments.

Comment: I've tried several work arounds, none of them work very well.  It's  nice that my first version (intercepting the turtle commands and creating direct tkinter calls) works reasonably well for my current usage.  I had hoped the tkinter canvas scraping approach would work as it might lead to a tkinter based interface for the blind.

Comment: I've tried several work arounds, none of them work very well.  It's  nice that my first version (intercepting the turtle commands and creating direct tkinter calls) works reasonably well for my current usage.  I had hoped the tkinter canvas scraping approach would work as it might lead to a tkinter based interface for the blind.  My attempts so far appear to make Canvas find_overlapping() give results whose locations to not correspond to the created objects.  I'm not sure if the problem is strictly negative coordinates.

Comment: Code must be posted as text. Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: My apologies.  This posting was to indicate the environment was IDLE.  The actual code is of little significance here.  For complete code please refer to GitHub/raysmith619 resource_lib/src/ or TurtleBraille/src/.   A more detailed description of my problem continues in TurtleBraille/readme.md  Thanks for your concern.